# Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval'

Tags: ruby, selenium, phantomjs, watir

Hi guys i'm using `phantomjs` to do automation testing. Here is my code:

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.phantomjs("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36")
  proxies = ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--web-security=false', '--ssl-protocol=any']
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs, :desired_capabilities => capabilities , :args => proxies

  browser = Watir::Browser.new driver      
begin
  browser.goto(url)
  browser.goto url
  browser.driver.execute_script( "window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight/2)" )
  sleep 1
  browser.driver.execute_script( "window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)" )
  sleep 1
  response = browser.html
  fileHtml = File.new("response_linkedin.html", "wb+")
  fileHtml.puts(response)
  fileHtml.close
  browser.close
  response
rescue Exception => e
  raise e.message.to_s
ensure
  browser.close
end
```

The problem is when i tried to execute script `window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight/2)` to scroll window, my code returning error like below:

> "errorMessage":"Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive

i was wondering why i couldn't run script inside `phantomjs` ? for notes: i am using `phantomjs` version 2.2.1, for some people suggests me to downgrade version 1.9.8 ([source](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13114)), unfortunately downgrade to version 1.9.8 seems don't work. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem running javascript in phantomjs.

1. Try [watir-scroll](https://github.com/p0deje/watir-scroll), it's life changing if you need to move around the viewport with Watir.
2. With the latest version of Watir, you can now easily try out the latest Chrome Headless features:

   Watir.browser.new(:chrome, {headless: true, args: args}

With the [phantomjs maintainer stepping down](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE), there will be a lot more energy directed toward the headless features in Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: Hi thanks, i was wondering if was using `headless chrome`, how could i spoof browser with fake user agents ?

Comment: `options: {emulation: {userAgent: 'foo;bar'}` - https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/master/spec/browser_spec.rb#L83

Comment: Thanks mate your suggestion helps me alot

Comment: There is a #watir channel in the Selenium Slack if you want to discuss this any further. http://seleniumhq.herokuapp.com/